# How to create a Hashtable with array

Tags: java, hashtable

I have a list of forms, which are kept in an array list (example values: F1, F2, ..., F7), and a list of user ids (example values: 1,2, 3). I need to have a table which contains user id and a list of forms such as Hashtable, where integer value is a user id (f.ex. 1) and ArrayList is a list of forms this user can access (f.ex. for user 1 they are F2, F3). How can I create this hashtable so that arraylist for every matched user id contains the values from the list of forms?

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
Map<Integer,List<String>> yourList = new HashMap<Integer,List<String>>();
```

That pretty much fits your requirement - the `Integer` is your user ID and the `List<String>` can hold the allowed forms for that user.

Also: Ditto @Tichodroma's comment!

Cheers,

Comment: How do i fill this Map then?

Comment: yourList.put(1, new ArrayList(F2, F3))? This is not correct, but I need to do like this

Comment: If you have to ask that question, you should probably first read Goslings book: http://www.amazon.com/The-Java%C2%BF-Programming-Language-Edition/dp/0321349806